# Can I use thymeleaf spring security like jstl

Tags: thymeleaf

I wish to put part of javascript code depends on authorities like below which is freemarker code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></br>
var openAuthorityOperatorData = false;

$(function() {
    $('#dlg_operator_auth_search_form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500<@security.authorize access="hasRole('AUHOA00000')"> + 450</@security.authorize>,
        height: 550,
        dialogClass: 'dialog-shadow',
        modal: false,
        resizable: false...
})});
</script>
```

With thymleaf, I can only find a way that puts authority attribute into script element like below.

```
<script sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('AUCOP0000x','AUUOP0000x')" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
}); 
</script>
```

If I can not use something like the top code, can I use jstl with thymeleaf to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf requires valid HTML5/XHTML/XML templates to work, so it is not possible to combine it with JSTL.

However, you can use script inlining in Thymeleaf. The Spring Security extras plugin also provides an `authorization` utility object.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var w = /*[[${#authorization.expression('hasAnyRole(''AUCOP0000x'',''AUUOP0000x'')')} ? ${500} : ${950} ]]*/ 500;
    ...
        width: w,
    ...
</script>
```

**Sources**

- [Thymeleaf Script inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)
- [Thymeleaf Spring Security authorization object](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3#using-the-expression-utility-objects)